# jquery dialog closes when going to vb code

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

```
 function test() {
$("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
return true;
}
```

asp:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
  <ItemTemplate> 
     <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" onClick="haha_click" OnClientClick="test();" ClientIDMode="Static" class="someclass"  runat="server">link</asp:LinkButton>
   </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

vb:

```
Protected Sub haha_click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    msgBox("test")
End Sub
```

when i run my code, on the client click the dialog opens and on click it goes to the vb code but closes the dialog... so how can i prevent the dialog from closing when going to the vb code?

Comment: You can do this if you use ajax

Comment: @RameshRajendran can you tell me how please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the button the page is posted to the server. The browser renders the returned response which in effect destroys the current page (to put it simply). The easiest solution is to use Ajax instead of regular post. Wrap the contents of the dialog in an `UpdatePanel` control.

Comment: okey and how do i call the script function to open the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

When a PostBack occurs it will reload the page, any DOM changes via javascript will have been lost. And you must make these changes again once the page has re-loaded

You can add the following line of code to re-open the dialog after the page refresh if required.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "Re-Open my jQuery Dialog", "<script type=""text/javascript"">test();</script>")
```